# Why can't I find jsoncpp.lib in the WebRTC source code?

Tags: webrtc, jsoncpp

WebRTC Native APIs

I downloaded the source code `WebRTC.Normally` there will be a file jsoncpp.lib in `obj\third_party\jsoncpp\jsoncpp.lib` but I can't find the file jsoncpp.lib on the code i downloaded.

The code I downloaded has the following structure: `obj\third_party\jsoncpp\`

1. There is 1 folder named `jsoncpp`(have 3 file `.obj: json_reader.obj,    json_value.obj, json_writer.obj)`
2. And 2 file: `jsoncpp.ninja, jsoncpp.stamp`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEqMD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQUyJ.png)

I didn't find `jsoncpp.lib` library file from `webRTC` so I downloaded `jsoncpp` library from `jsoncpp` homepage source code on GitHub but it didn't fix my error